# What are "class rolls"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

I found this expression while [preparing](http://takeielts.britishcouncil.org/prepare-test/free-sample-tests/reading-sample-test-1-general-training/section-1-questions-1%E2%80%9314) for the IELTS test:

> "Teachers will take the **class rolls**."

What are these "class rolls"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression "take roll" means to "record which students are (and are not) in attendance." The teachers will call out the names of the students and note which students are present. We also use the expression "call roll" with the same meaning.

You can read the definition [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+roll).

The [roll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll_call) itself is the actual list of students who *should* be there. It may also be referred to as a class list or class register.

Comment: Also note that you "enroll" your child or yourself in a class when registering for it.